# Unable to add DbModelBuilder and .HasRequired() to modelBuilder

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-builder

I am trying to create a ModelBuilder within my API and can't seem to add `.HasRequired()` to my code.  I am assuming this is due to the fact that it lives within `DBModelBuilder`, however, I cannot add that also.

It will only allow me to use `ModelBuilder`.
Otherwise it throws an error: `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder): no suitable method found to override`

Am I missing something here?

My DbContext looks like so:

```
public class TicketContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Tickets> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) // <-- Not allowing me to add DbModelBuilder here
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tickets>().HasRequired(t => t.Users);

        }
    }
```

### Update

I have (as a test) started a new project from scratch.  I created a new ASP.NET 5.0 project using a Web API template.  Straight away my project doesn't recognize `DbModelBuilder`.  I added reference to EntityFramework.dll and still no good.  I then added `using System.Data.Entity;` and it then accepted `DbModelBuilder` but still complains that the namespace 'DbModelBuilder' could not be found.

I can't understand how I can have this error upfront on a brand new project?

As soon as I try and add the package Entity Framework from NuGet, I get more errors that version 6.1.3 is not compatible with DNX Core 5.0

I can't seem to find any examples/solutions to any of these errors.

### Update 2

I have managed to get DbModelBuilder recognized now by adding the EntityFramework.dll reference to the DNX Core 5.0 Assembly as well as the DNX 4.5.1 assembly, however, now it has thrown even more errors wanting System.Core added and mscorlib.  I really can't believe how much trouble it is to create a (what I thought would be simple) Web API project.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, it just keeps getting this error that OnModelCreating has no override. I don't understand why. It's worked just fine before but now it won't.

Comment: I'm not sure sorry.  I gave up with this in the end.  Seemed too much trouble for such a simple exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call HasRequired off the model builder - you need to indicate the entity you want to change:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    { 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasRequired(f => f.Bar);   // assumes Bar navigation added to Foo
    } 
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

What I like to do is separate out my fluent code like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    { 
       modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooConfig());
    }
```

Now I can create a class with all my mapping for that entity:

```
public class FooConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfig()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.FooId);

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(f => f.Bar).WithMany(b => b.Foos);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific.  I have updated my post to show my current code that isn't working.

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't recognise `DbModelBuilder` only `ModelBuilder`, so I can't add `.HasRequired()`.

Comment: If you use System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder does it work?

Comment: No, I get the error: `The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'`

Comment: What's your EF version?

Comment: I'm assuming it's `EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final"`.  If not, could you please tell me where I can find this for you.  Thanks

Comment: Got to run out, but looks like you may be missing a reference

Comment: I would also like to separate out my fluent code, but I cannot add the DbModelBuilder as an parameter to my method without adding the EnittyFramework reference to my project containing the Fluent API code, and adding just the System.Data.Entity dll did not work. Please have a look at my question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141356/cannot-use-dbmodelbuilder-in-seperate-project

Comment: In the latest release of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, the OnModelCreating override accepts a ModelBuilder and not a DbModelBuilder, so when you attempt to use `builder.Entity<SomeEntity>().HasRequired`, it's missing.  Try the latest release and you'll see.  There is not .HasRequired