# Cannot use DbModelBuilder in separate project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my solution, I have a few projects, all together forming part of one web application.

I am busy setting up Entity Framework, and in my context class, instead of having to write all my fluent API code in the

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

method, I want to be able to create a method in my `Model` classes called `ConfigureModel`, and then configure all the primary key/foreign key settings there, so it should look something as follow:

```
public class UserRolesModel : ModelBase
{
    #region Configuration

    public static void ConfigureModel(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //necessary code here
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And, for example, call the method as follow:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    UserRolesModel.ConfigureModel(modelBuilder);
}
```

The problem I am facing is in my `ConfigureModel` method: I cannot seem to resolve the `DbModelBuilder` reference. Even if I added the `System.Data.Entity` dll to my references, it did not work. I needed to install Entity Framework to this separate project as well for this to work.

Surely I do not have to add EF to every project I would like to use the `DbModelBuilder` in?

What is another way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you reference the correct .Net version? By the way, this is much easier with NuGet. Just add the package to your projects. But... shouldn't the configurations take place in the EF assembly, so you can decouple the class assemblies from EF?

Comment: @GertArnold I have a project called Common in my solution, where I place all models that will be used all over the project. Since these models will be the map to my Tables, I would like to do the configuration inside them. Where would you suggest I do all the necessary configuration?

Comment: I don't know, not knowing your project. But I wouldn't like the idea of multiple libraries all depending on EF. Maybe one mapping assembly doing all the mapping?

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the ideas. If I understand you correctly, do you maybe think, I should create a class, almost like the "Initialize" class in the assembly that references EntityFramework, and do all my mappings there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my 2 cents since you asked. Don't put fluent code in your models - that's bad separation of concerns and clutters them up (non-POCO). A good alternative to a giant OnModelCreating is this:

1) Make a folder in your project that has your context called "EntityConfigurations". In a large project you could divide it up even further like "EntityConfigurations\System",  "EntityConfigurations\Employee", etc. [From Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/11/28/composing-entity-framework-fluent-configurations.aspx)

2) Add classes for each item:

```
public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.ProductId);
        Property(p => p.ProductName)
           .IsRequired()
           .HasMaxLength(200);
        ...
    }

}
```

3) Use AddFromAssembly and your mapping classes will be discovered and run automatically. [From Julie Lerman.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519921.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

This has worked well for our team. You hardly ever look at the fluent code so keeping it out of the model we look at daily is a good thing.

Comment: I really like this approach, thanks for your effort and time. If I do this within the same project as my "Data Access Layer", it will also mean I do not have to add the EntityFramework.dll in another project where it is not really necessary.  Thanks once again, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where my dependent project was unable to resolve references related to EF

I had to add the reference of the 2 assemblies, EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll to the project that was complaining which fixed the issue.

Comment: Well you are basically telling me that you had sort of the same issue as me, and you fixed it eventually by adding the EnittyFramework.dll, which is what I did as well.